# Mongodb DeprecationWarning: count is deprecated. Use Collection.count_documents instead

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

[image]

I want to query with Python mongodb but "DeprecationWarning: count is deprecated. Use Collection.count_documents instead." gives such an error. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the new method `count_documents` as `count` is deprecated

```
mycol.count_documents(myquery)
```

https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=count#pymongo.collection.Collection.count_documents

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/

Comment: "AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'count_documents'" It gives this error this time

Comment: @Bilalİnal try this `mycol.count_documents(myquery)
`